# Dapper - "Must declare the scalar variable @VersionId"

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, dapper

I'm attempting to use Dapper to perform some simple queries into a database that is available on my local machine.

Most of the queries are working fine, but when I attempt to insert an object into its corresponding table in the database I get an `SqlException`. I have a similar insert method that first instantiates an object within the method body and inserts it into the database, and that method works fine. But this one doesn't. More specifically, this is the response from the exception:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Must declare the scalar variable "@VersionId".'
```

Here is the calling code that produces the exception:

```
public int CreateNewSchema(Schema schema)
        {
            string sql = "INSERT INTO Schemas(VersionId, Created, Updated, SchemaData) " +
                         " values (@VersionId, @Created, @Updated, @SchemaData);";

            var affectedRows = _connection.Execute(sql, new{schema});
            return affectedRows;
        }
```

The corresponding Schema table in my database has the following design.

```
Schema 
ID             int
VersionID      nvarchar(max)
Created        datetime2(7)
Updated        datetime2(7)
SchemaData     nvarchar(max)
```

And finally, the POCO object I am attempting to insert into this table is defined as follows:

```
public class Schema
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string VersionId { get; set; }
        public DateTime Created { get; set; }
        public DateTime Updated { get; set; }
        public string SchemaData { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: VersionID != VersionId is that the problem?

Comment: @GeertBellekens and neither SQL nor Dapper cares. That's not the problem

Comment: Spelling mistake, the column in the table is `VersionId` and matches other declarations.

Comment: @VDWWD not related. This is a question about *Dapper* which uses reflection to extract parameter names and values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pass object directly:

```
var affectedRows = _connection.Execute(sql, schema);
```

Dapper analysing properties of passed object.

You passed object with only one property `schema`. So `@schema` would be the only variable you will get in your query. If you pass object as is, not as part of another object, you will get variables you expect, that correspond to `Schema` object properties.

Comment: Correct solution, fixed my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You passed an object containing a property named `schema` who's value is the schema object.

Dapper uses reflection to find the property names and match them to parameters in the query. You *don't* need to create an anonymous type.

Anonymous types are used for convenience, to avoid creating a regular type just to pass a few parameters. That's used extensively in Dapper, ASP.NET MVC, LINQ and anywhere one needs to pass a bunch of properties but doesn't want to create a new type.

Just pass the schema object :

```
var affectedRows = _connection.Execute(sql, schema);
```

Comment: Fantastic, your solution worked perfectly. I know for future now. Thanks!

Comment: @Jake12342134 lorond spotted it first. I just added the explanation